# JS coutdown times not show

Tags: javascript

In my site page I have a simple countdown timer:
`{{ $tournaments->end }}` is parsed information from MySQL, like this: `2020-07-27 03:17:36` and in MySQL field with time has `timestamp` format.

At my view blade i use:

```js
function create_target_date() {
  var target_date = new Date(`2020-07-27 03:17:36`) // {{$tournaments -> end}}
  //target_date.setDate(target_date.getDate()+1);
  target_date.setHours(23, 59, 59);
  return target_date;
}

function calculation_timer() {
  var target_date = create_target_date();
  var current_date = new Date();
  val_timer = target_date.getTime() - current_date.getTime();

  var hours = Math.floor(val_timer / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((val_timer - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000 / 60);
  var seconds = Math.floor(((val_timer - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) - minutes * 60 * 1000) / 1000);

  document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = hours;

  document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = minutes;

  document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
}

function start_timer() {
  calculation_timer();
  id_timer = setInterval(calculation_timer, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload='start_timer();'>
  (<span id='hours'></span><span id='hours_legend'></span>:<span id='minutes'></span><span id='minutes_legend'>:</span><span id='seconds'></span><span id='seconds_legend'></span>)
  </span>
  </span>
</body>
```

But nothing don't show, at my page timer doesn't want to show.

If see the source code, it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` at line `var target_date = new Date({{ $tournaments->end }});` and another error `start_timer is not defined` but i have `start_timer()` function.

And if see the page source code, it show:

```
   function create_target_date() 
    {
        var target_date = new Date(2020-07-27 03:17:36);
        //target_date.setDate(target_date.getDate()+1);
        target_date.setHours(23,59,59);
        return target_date;
    }
```

I mean date parse sucessful. How i can make the timer show, where is my mistake?

Comment: Your code works when I make a snippet using the string you suggest - the string must be quoted or in template backticks like I did otherwise it sounds like the {{ ... }} is not parsed in the page. Look at view-source -

Comment: You can't use the date directly like that, it should be in quotes to make it a string... `new Date("2020-07-27 03:17:36");`

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed quotes. Here is a slicker version

```js
const pad = num => ("0" + num).slice(-2);
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const target_date = new Date(`2020-07-27 03:17:36`) // `{{$tournaments -> end}}`
  target_date.setHours(23, 59, 59);
  const output = document.getElementById("time");
  const id_timer = setInterval(function() {
    const current_date = new Date();
    const diff = target_date.getTime() - current_date.getTime();
    const hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((diff - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000 / 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor(((diff - hours * 60 * 60 * 1000) - minutes * 60 * 1000) / 1000);
    time.innerHTML = `${pad(hours)}:${pad(minutes)}:${pad(seconds)}`
  }, 1000);
})
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>
```